# NPM Cannot find module 'safe-buffer'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

Since I have installed yarn, I cannot use `npm` anymore.

`NodeJS` is well upgraded. Impossible to remove `npm`. Every command I do I got the same error message:

```
 module.js:487
     throw err;
 ^


 Error: Cannot find module 'safe-buffer'
     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:485:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:437:25)
   at Module.require (module.js:513:17)     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:56:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
```

I got:
NodeJS v8.2.1,
Yarn v0.27.5
(can't `npm -v` my npm)

Already tried:

- remove node_modules folder from my projet and re-install it using npm
  install (got same error message).
- `npm upgrade`, `npm cache clear`,
  `npm cache rm`, `npm install safe buffer`

I got only 22 lines on my file `module.js` the error message is talking about, so I cannot have a line 437, 513 or 569 to check.

Comment: Have you googled "Error: Cannot find module 'safe-buffer' at Function.Module._resolveFilename"? There are plenty of similar problems and suggested solutions. Try updating / re-installing NPM.

Comment: You need run npm install in the directory with your package.json.

Comment: I tried many thing I found on Google since two days, or similar error. But still got it. I had also removed the node_modules from my project and run npm install (at the same place of my package.jason), but I got the same message for all npm command.

Answer (score 2):

It was impossible to uninstall npm, so I re-install NodeJS from :
https://nodejs.org/en/

And it's finally work.

Answer (score 0):

Actually in my machine even delete global `npm` or `uninstall` `node.js` and install it again but still not work.

---

so my solution is `uninstall npm` and go to delete folder `npm` and `npm-cache` in `C:\Users\pc-name\AppData\Roaming` then install it again

Answer (score 0):

I use nvm, so I deleted the `node_modules` directory there:

`rm -rf /Users/shawn/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules`

Then I ran `npm install` and everything worked.